# MyCentOSー...というタイトルの実行画面や、Python コードの編集画面を出す方法

Tags: python, macos, python3

プログラミング初心者です。「ドットインストール」というサイトの動画で勉強しています。動画の画像では「myapp.py」のタブと「MyCentOSー...」の二つがスクリーン上にありますが、その二つはどうやって起動させるのですか？　（自分の画像：IDLEで「Python3.6.1 Shell」は起動できました。）

動画の画像:
[image: 動画の画像]

自分の画像:
[image: 自分の画像]

Comment: 質問内容がはっきりしないと思います，もうちょっと具体的にどこが「違う」ということなのかを説明して頂けるとやりやすいと思います．まず「動画で使用しているもの」が何を指しているかがわからないのと上と下でそもそもコードが違ってるのでなんとも言えません…が、とりあえずエラーが出ているのは Python 3 では `print` は関数になったので括弧が必要だからです（Python 2 では要らなかった）． `print 3` は駄目， `print(3)` にしましょう．

Comment: Yoshさん、回答ありがとうございます。質問内容を明確化したので、もう一度ご回答お願いします。

Answer (score 2):

動画サイトを見てみました。

リンクのページの「補足情報 必要となる知識について」というところで 開発環境の構築の動画ありますので まずはそちらを視聴すれば 動画と同じ環境が作れるのではと思います。

[#01 Pythonを使ってみよう | Python 3入門 - プログラミングならドットインストール](http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_python_v3/38701)

なお、「myapp.py」のタブは Atom というテキストエディタのようです。
動画では「なんでも良いのですが今回はAtom」と解説されてますね。

Answer (score 1):

動画では仮想マシンとエディタ、端末を使っている様ですね。

#### IDLE を使う場合

- IDLE のメニューの "File" メニューにある、"New File" や、"Open" の項目でエディタ画面が開きます。
- エディタでコードを打ち込み、メニューの "File" -> "Save" などでファイルに保存します。
- エディタのメニューの "Run" -> "Run Module" で実行します。

実行すると、IDLE のシェルがリセットされ、`print` などの出力があるなら、表示されるはずです。

#### 動画に合わせる場合

[take88 さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/35514/3054) を参照下さい。
（IDLE は最初にとりあえず動かすのには便利で優れていると思いますが、いずれ卒業する物です。動画に完全に合わせないとしても、エディタとターミナルの使い方などは覚えておくとよいと思います）

Comment: mjyさんご回答ありがとうございます。エディタ画面を開くところまでできました。無事解決です。